# jQuery Accordion | Open first element on pageload & active state confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Javascript below to animate an accordion (it's a slightly modified variant of the one explained here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/26/elegant-accordion-with-jquery-and-css3/.

Now I wanted to have the first element to be open on pageload, so I figured I just give it some sort of extra-class via Javascript (and define that `.active` state via CSS) to have it open up.

This worked, however if I hover over any but the `first-element` with said `.active` class, the first element keeps its state, and stays open until I hover over it at least once.

So, what I want is: the first element of my accordion is open and collapses if the user hovers over **any of the elements that are not the first**. I think I need to add a line in the `hover` function to either take the class away of the first element or to give the new element the active state, but I don't know how to do it and keep breaking the thing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function() {

            activeItem = jQuery("#accordion li:first");
            jQuery(activeItem).addClass('active');

            jQuery('#accordion > li, #accordion > li.heading').hover(
                function () {
                    var jQuerythis = jQuery(this);
                    jQuerythis.stop().animate({'height':'280px'},500);
                    jQuery('.heading',jQuerythis).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                    jQuery('.bgDescription',jQuerythis).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                    jQuery('.description',jQuerythis).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                },

                function () {
                    var jQuerythis = jQuery(this);
                    jQuerythis.stop().animate({'height':'40px'},1000);
                    jQuery('.heading',jQuerythis).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    jQuery('.description',jQuerythis).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
                    jQuery('.bgDescription',jQuerythis).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is happening because each accordion item has its own hover event that takes care of its own animation. You can refactor the code slightly to make this easier to understand and reuse:

```js
        var activeItem = jQuery("#accordion li:first");

        jQuery('#accordion > li, #accordion > li.heading').hover(
            function () { hoverMe(jQuery(this)); },
            function () { unhoverMe(jQuery(this)); }
        );

        //This gets called when cursor hovers over any accordion item
        var hoverMe = function(jQuerythis) {

            //If the first item is still active
            if (activeItem) {
                contract(activeItem); //...Shrink it!
                activeItem = false;
            }

            //Expand the accordion item
            expand(jQuerythis);
        };

        //This gets called when cursor moves out of accordion item
        var unhoverMe = function(jQuerythis) {
                contract(jQuerythis);
        };

        //I have moved the hover animation out into a separate function, so we can call it on page load
        var expand = function(jQuerythis) {
                jQuerythis.stop().animate({'height':'280px'},500);
                jQuery('.heading',jQuerythis).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                jQuery('.bgDescription',jQuerythis).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                jQuery('.description',jQuerythis).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
        };

        //I have moved the unhover animation out into a separate function, so we can contract the first active item from hoverMe()
        var contract = function() {
                jQuerythis.stop().animate({'height':'40px'},1000);
                jQuery('.heading',jQuerythis).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                jQuery('.description',jQuerythis).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
                jQuery('.bgDescription',jQuerythis).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
        };

        //Now expand the first item
        expand(activeItem);
```

I have put together [**a simplified version**](http://jsfiddle.net/VnVaF/1/) demonstrating the logic. Please let me know how you get on.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks for the annotations too! This does exactly what I need it to do!